# What to put in 60A GFCI breakers in Subpanel?

Tags: electrical-panel

Update: I was asking "What to put in 60A GFCI breakers in Subpanel?" 
Answer: maybe The main panel! That is, the main panel would be the subpanel of the 60A GFCI breaker. It's like the main panel and subpanel got swapped!

Detail. I was asking what to put in 60A GFCI breaker in subpanel in case I'd need to swap the 30A to the bath heaters and 60A to other loads. Here is an idea (Harper and others familiar with my setup).

My purely 240v main panel has this remaining loads (all are 30A breakers and all using AWG 10 even to the lights):

[image]

What if I'd separate the main breaker and body in the main panel. Then the main breaker would connected to the subpanel. And the main body in main panel would become the subpanel of the 60A output of the original subpanel. Here:

[image]

So it's like the subpanel and main panel become swapped. And the original main panel would now be the output of 60A of this original subpanel:

[image]

I'd use 60A GFCI breaker number 5. This can totally eliminate all the wire nuts in the original panel above which is due to 3 circuits joined into one breaker. I'd put them in original breaker.

In essence. What to put in 60A GFCI breakers in Subpanel? The main panel (minus the main breaker which will be connected to the subpanel, but rest of main panel will be output of the 60A GFCI breaker).

This way, the entire house will be protected by GFCI. Not only that. Even the entire main panel chassis will be protected too (and it can be covered without fear of electrified chassis since it can trip the 5mA GFCI).

But big question. Can the 60A GFCI breaker have the following loads (the remaining original panel loads and the ones in GFCI breaker 5 to be transferred and added to the loads)?

1. Aircon 2.4hp room 2 (9A)    (number 1 to 5 is from remaining loads)
2. Aircon 2.5hp sala (10A)
3. Aircon 1.5hp room 3 (5A)
4. Aircon 1hp room 1 (3A)
5. Lights ground floor (1A), 2nd floor (0.5A), attic (0.5A)
6. Room 2 outlets (3A) (from original subpanel no. 5 GFCI breaker)
7. Kitchen outlets (0.5A) (from original subpanel no. 5 GFCI breaker)
8. Attic outlets (2A) (from original subpanel no. 5 GFCI breaker)

total load is 35A that will use the 60A GFCI breaker output. Again each wiring is AWG 10 and each non GFCI breaker in original panel is 30A.

Will this work? This way the aircons are each in their original 30A breaker.

Brilliant idea or technically flawed? Lol.

original message yesterday:

Last year I bought 6 GFCI breakers. 2 pcs are 60A, 4 pcs are 30A. I initially bought the 60A at amazon because it is the cheapest. I wasn't thinking then about the wire and breaker matching then as I didn't know about it yet.

[image]

These are my exact loads presently running. I turned off all the breakers because I just put the 100A main breaker.

[image]

Bigger view.

[image]

I'm presently using each 60A breaker for 6000W bath heater (I have 2 heaters, each connected separately to 60A breaker as shown in the actual breaker pics). I know 6000W/240v= 25A. Wire used for all are AWG 10. My question. Someone told me I must use 30A for the 25A heater. But even if you have a single TV say 1A, you still use 10A breaker in the house for that single load. So how come I can't use the 25A bath heater in the 60A ampere when it's the only load? I mean, the wiring to the 60A won't overload because the only load is the 25A bath heater and nothing else put on that 60A breaker. At least it should trip if there is a short in the heater. But the AWG 10 which has capacity of 30A to 35A won't melt at all because the only load is 25A heater. So why can't you use it on the 60A breaker? NEC may not allow it. But what is the logical and technical reasoning for it?

Also in case I'll swap the 30A for the heater. What would I put in the 60A GFCI breakers then, the TV or fridges? All the other 4 loads are just low enough that even when I combined many appliances in one breaker. It won't exceed 10A in the rest of the 4 30A GFCI breakers in above label pic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the breaker needs to protect both the loads and the wires. There are (at least) 3 different ways your 25A heater could fail, requiring a breaker trip:

- Short Circuit - That is easy. A short pulling hundreds of Amps (or whatever the service will supply) will trip a 60A breaker almost as fast as it would trip a 30A breaker. **Good**
- Ground Fault - A ground fault will trip a GFCI breaker at very low current, no matter what the rating of the breaker is (30A vs. 60A). **Good**
- Moderate overload - This is the real problem. If you have some sort of fault in the heater - perhaps a component starting to fail but not totally failing (because if it totally failed it would either fail open - safe - or fail closed - short circuit). **BAD** In this situation, you could have 40A or 50A flowing through and it would not trip the 60A breaker. **But it would melt your wires and start a fire.**

Comment: Presently, my AWG 10 wires to the heaters from the breakers pass through outside the house in conduit. Can I just upgrade the wires then to match the breaker 60A? What size must I use? And this setup would be ok? a 25A heater connected to 60A breaker and wire sized for 60A?

Comment: That would solve the wire vs. breaker mismatch. But the device (heater in this case) vs. breaker size is still an issue. If the device were to have a partial failure resulting in a constant 40A running through it, the breaker would not trip, the upgraded wires would be fine, but your heater - and quite possibly surrounding furnishings - might catch on fire. Not a likely problem, but breakers are to protect against the *unlikely* problems.

Comment: How about this. I'd put two of these 30A breakers after the 60A to power each 25A bath heaters. Or 30A rail din breakers after the 60A. I don't want anothe space consuming panel. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/924/t1YX1Q.jpg

Answer (score 2):

### Breakers protect wires more than loads

If we only built for circuits working the way they're supposed to, we wouldn't need **any of this stuff**.

The purpose of  breakering 10AWG at 30A is to ensure that misconfiguration or malfunction doesn't pull, say, 55A over that wire and overheat it.  As an aside, it also protects the house from whatever happens inside the equipment when it pulls 55A instead of 24A.

I would re-task the 60A breakers to feed other subpanels.  They're a bit large to use for small appliance branch circuits.

Comment: But what kind of malfunction can pull 55A in a heater that has only maximum 6000watts heating elements so 6000w/240v=25A only? Do you mean I have to buy another 2 pcs of 30A GFCI breakers? It's expensive. I want to use the 60A GFCI breakers. What loads can I put in them instead if I'll swap it with the other loads (shown in the load chart)?

Comment: Subpanels sound like a good solution to me. You get the proper **per circuit** protection while still getting the overall GFCI that was the goal of this project.

Comment: the above was already a subpanel feeding from a main panel. You mean I'll put another subpanel from the subpanel above? It's not an option because my home co-owners don't want me to put more panels. And you mean the only use for the 60A breaker is to feed subpanel, and I don't want a subpanel, then I must buy 2 more lower amperage GFCI breakers, like maybe 20A for the other loads (exchanging the 30A to the heater instead)?

Comment: the idea is that in the sub-sub-panel, you'll have $10 breakers protecting your 10-20 amp branch circuits.  The GFCI will protect the works.

Comment: Funny. My main panel has 16 breakers. 10 Breakers went to the Subpanel into 6 GFCI breakers. If I put another subpanel to feed off the GFCI breakers, then it's back to 16 breakers again. I should have gotten a 20 space subpanel instead of just present 12 space. That way I could put 10 GFCI breaker instead of just 6. It would be too much work. But maybe best is jus replacing the main panel with 20 space Siemens panel and put 10 GFCI breakers to power all loads, isn't it. My parents don't want me to add another panel, it's consuming space in the kitchen.

Comment: Harper. You mean the sub-sub-panel would only be feeded off a single GFCI breaker in the subpanel at present, right? Do you know of a good 4 space (or 2 breaker) DIN Rail that is compact that I can plug the 2 heaters to? It would be safe to put in main panel cabinet since it is already GFCI protected. Also European Din Rail housing is mostly plastic. Maybe it is arc flash resistant?

Comment: Past the GFCI any local brand of  panel would do.  The hard part is behind you.

Comment: do you think those tiny European din rail plastic enclosures are arc flash resistant? Are polycarbonate enclosure arc flash in general? If not. What are the plastic that are arc flash proof? And if I use a European 30A din rail AFCI breaker, then it can trip when arc is about to form, right? or after arc was formed that AFCI trips?

Comment: My God, I just watched this video of what arc flash can do.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY  I thought when you mentioned arc flash. It's just tiny millimeter arc and flash. But it looks like a grenade going off. I'll get back to your shutter (large junction box) plan as priority as I now realized a wooden cabinet is useless. It's scary. Had I seen the video last year, I couldn't have done any GFCI breaker addition. Also now i'm appreciating what AFCI can do. Is there a 100A AFCI that can I put before the main panel so it can protect everything? I don't want separate 6 pc AFCI

Comment: Yes, now you understand my paranoia about having all service panels fully steel encased.  Unfortunately there's not large AFCIs, , I have searched myself.  Part of the issue is that AFCIs *literally listen to the sound* of the circuit, arc faults sound exactly like hooking up speakers with the power on.  If the circuit beyond the AFCI is too complex, it muddies the sound.

Comment: @Harper. Please see edited post about swapping subpanel and main panel. This way. The main panel chassis would be GFCI protected being output of the 60A in original subpanel. Please edit your answer for the additional information whether all those main panels loads can use a single 60A GFCI with wiring sized for 60A of course. Many Thanks.

Comment: @Jtl that proposal is excellent.   Great way to do it, providing it's possible to mechanically peform the work in a quality way.

Comment: Please look at this photo with the main breaker bare https://imageshack.com/a/img924/803/OE1xyD.jpg and https://imageshack.com/a/img922/3256/T9SzBY.jpg (net pic of the GE model) . It's so big and already old. I need to replace it with something smaller to feed the subpanel directly and then with the 60A GFCI breaker driving the entire main panel as proposed. Should I need 125A new breaker or should it be 100A. And most important,wat is the most advance breaker model you know that has same form factor as it where you could insert the wires through holes at input & output and not needing plugin?

Comment: @Jtl no, that old breaker is *excellent* quality.  It fits your panel, so keep it.  Also, the way it is bussed is very suitable for your plan.  GE makes the best in the business. And 125A will be fine as it is within the capacity of thewires it is here to protect.

Comment: Ok. In typical American homes. What AWG do you use for main panel? I'm wondering whether to change the 30mm^2 to 38mm^2 since it will power the entire house and I don't want to take derating into account. What if the loads become maximum in future or 100% instead of 83%?

Comment: Given that you have a 150A feed breaker ouside, I would size it for 150A, based on the calcs in my other post.

Comment: Ok. To manuever 38^mm^2 wire inside panel..what is the minimum bend radius. I think if bent smaller radius. It can break? Do you have table for different bent radius for different wire sizes? Tnx

Comment: @Harper. Also consider the gap is only about 1.8 inches vertical. see: https://imageshack.com/a/img921/352/P7hhWL.jpg  How can I connect (and maneuver) a pair of 38mm^2 (between #2 & #1) in the upper breaker (after disconnecting the two vertical cooper). And a pair of AWG 6 to connect to screw lugs shown (this will be connected to the subpanel 60A load output)? Do you think the two pairs of wires can fit?) They can almost touch each other. No violation in any NEC rule?

Comment: btw.. in this pic.. https://imageshack.com/a/img924/803/OE1xyD.jpg   the wires connected in the line side of the main breaker is exactly 38mm^2. So imagine how it can fit it in the 1.8 inches vertical space in the load side. Not only that. Adding another pair of AWG 6 in the lugs below (the vertical cooper to be removed). Don't miss the other 2 related comments above. Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Harper. Someone made me realized I couldn't use the existing 125A GE breaker because it's not possible to put lugs into this without breaking it apart so I need to buy a new one... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/923/4iRTrJ.jpg and so I decided to put din rail breakers which are mostly used in new condominium and houses in the country. They are more compact and can make me maneuver wires more easily.  Now since my choice is either 30mm^2 or 38mm^2. Even 38mm^2 has 122A at 75C. It may burn before the 125A trip during maximum usage.Therefore can I just buy a 100A din rail breaker?

Comment: You can unscrew the screws at the top of the busbars in that photo.  Then it should be possible to fit lugs where the busbars were.  Remember, all of this is downline of a 150A breaker which is outside.  If your feeder wire is adequate to 150A, and as I revealed, 38mm2 wire is indeed adequate... then can hotwire straight to the Siemens panel's main.  Then, from a 60A GFCI to the top of the GE main.

Comment: But if you will read this Answer by ThreePhaseEel in https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156959/what-is-the-type-size-or-part-number-of-this-breaker-terminal-allen-screw/157021#157021 one can't put any lugs to it because it's not field convertible as he said. Also between my 150A outside in street and main panel, there is another disconnect see https://imageshack.com/a/img923/5663/2HKWhz.jpg but I want to connect a 100A din rail before the Siemens in case the Siemens 100A breakers won't work since I opened the internal to peek inside.

Comment: Ok.  However the fact is you have plenty of breaker protection as your service comes in serially through two 150s.  The worst thing the Siemens 100A can do is fail to trip, and one of the 150s will still trip.  If the Siemens panel is physically capable of 150A, then that took-apart breaker is not needed  except as a shutoff switch.

Comment: But the 150A breaker outside is exposed to rain for 15 years so someone said the magnetic and thermal strip is so rusted it won't work anymore so the breaker is as good as wire only. Also I have concern about this 83% derating thing. Breakers are supposed to protect wires.. but derating can seem to violate it.. pls. answer at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157043/breakers-protect-wires-doesnt-83-derating-violate-it   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit breakers are designed to be the weakest link in the circuit. They have the ability to disconnect themselves in the event of a malfunction like a short circuit, ground fault or an overload. You do not want the wires (or your appliances) to be the weakest link in the system; they would overheat and melt, hidden inside a wall, potentially causing a fire. Additionally, appliances and devices you've outlined in your notes should not be powered with branch circuits rated any more than 15 Amps. Here in Canada residential lights, for example, are not to be powered by circuits rated at more than 15 Amps. And certain other loads, like refrigerators, are required to be supplied by their own dedicated branch circuit, sharing that load with nothing else.

Comment: In the Philippines. Any building lights always use 30A as minimum. Why should you only use 15A? What is the problem with 30A used with lights? It can still trip if there is overload. All the wiring in my house use AWG 10 smallest size for lights.

Comment: The narrow wires used in your lights could not handle 30 Amps. These wires would melt long before the 30 Amp breaker ever tripped. The breakers wouldn't ever detect a problem until well after everything had melted together. Remember; you want the breakers to be THE weakest, narrowest part of the entire system or circuit.

Comment: You are using oversized breakers (30 amps) and oversized conductors (awg #10), which is fine, but don't forget the rest of the system like the plugs; they are only designed for maybe 20 amps, maximum. And what about those appliances you plug into your circuits? The wiring inside these appliances are inly thick enou to handle 15 or 20 amps at the most. The wiring inside these appliances would therefore be the weakest link in the electrical system and they could melt and be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. In case I'd need to replace the two 60A and exchange the 30A from other loads to the two heaters. What amperage of the new GFCI breakers must I buy based on the loadings shown above and which ones of them must be plugged to the new say 15A GFCI breakes?

Comment: Chris. You said the narrow wires in the lights couldn't handle 30A. But is it not during a short circuit, even an AWG 18 wire can trip the 30A breaker?  Is there a situation the lights can draw 20A enough to melt the AWG 18 wire in overload situation which the 30A can't protect?

Comment: You *must* use the smallest size breakers possible in every case, not the largest size. This is the basic principle behind every electrical circuit everywhere. Using larger ampacity breakers will eventually burn your house down. A short circuit in an 18 gauge wire may or may not trip a large 30 amp breaker.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "CR heater" and "CR outlets". Your breaker's ampacities should be based on the rating of the appliances you are using. In Canada we generally use no more than 12 devices on each general 15 amp circuit (plugs, lights, and so on) assuming each dvice is requires about 1amp. That means the demand is only ever about 80% of what each breaker can provide. Any more than 12 amps on a 15 amp circuit and you're close to getting nuisance tripping. Throw away those four 40 amp breakers and replace them with 15's. And replace those two 60's with two 30's.

Comment: CR means Comfort Room or Restroom. I thought Comfort Room is a universal description for restroom, lol. I don't have four 40 amp breakers. My breakers are two 60A and four 30A. which will I throw or give away?  Which should I put the two 15's?

Comment: We call them 'bathrooms', 'restrooms' or simply 'washrooms'. We all have our own euphamisms, I suppose. Never ever install breakers unless you have done at least some kind of basic load calculations for each branch circuit. You'll probably require about eight 15 amp single-pole breakers for your general circuits. And I wouldn't use more than 25 or 30 amp breakers for the dedicated heater circuits.

Comment: You mean if you have just 2 lights, you can't put them on a 20A breaker? In the Philippines. Even with 1 light. We put them on 20A breaker. It can still trip the 20A in event of short, isn't it. And there is no way for 1 light to draw 10A or 20A to overload the light tiny wires themselves, isn't it.

Comment: I can't say. I am not familiar with building standards and electrical standards other than in Canada. I think you misunderstand the point of a breaker; it should be as small as possible, it must be the weakest link in the system, not the biggest. In Canada the smallest breaker for household circuits is 15 amps. And lights are not to be supplied by breakers greater than 15 amps.

Comment: For your 12 circuits with 1A each on one 15a breaker. What if at night you were sleeping and there is only 2A circuit that is power on. Won't it be like have 2A circuit on 15A breaker, because they are not on all the time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89234/discussion-between-chris-taylor-and-jtl).