# What is the type & size or part-number of this breaker terminal allen screw?

Tags: electrical-panel

I need to insert the wires directly at the bottom of it. Where can I find two extra terminal screw (allen type)? Is there standard size for this or proprietary (General Electric TQD22125)? What is its size?

[image]

This is another picture in the net for the GE TQD Series:

[image: nal]

Answer (score 1):

That could be a **[TCAL25 Connector Lug](https://www.widespreadsales.com/Products/Circuit-Breakers-General-Electric/TCAL25)**. That is what you would need on the breaker in the second picture.

[image]

However, you can also buy just the **[Set Screw](https://lugsdirect.com/AluminumSetScrews/AluminumSetScrews.htm)** separately. They come in many different sizes.

[image]

Comment: If i'd buy the set screw separately, what is the size?

Comment: I would guess that all of the GE TDQ models use the same type of screw. Those lugs with the screw are less than $5 each. Order a couple. If they don't work, you would have a screw in hand that you could use for a reference. You could also visit your local electric supply house that has those particular breakers in stock. Ask if they have some extras to sell or if they can tell you the correct size to order.

Comment: @Jtl this is a specific screw for this part. You would go to an electrical supply. They would order the screws based on what the part calls for; you don't have to give them the size.

Comment: @Jerry_Contrary Do you think the cooper strip use the same lugs where the cooper is put on top of it? or does it use an entirely different lugs for the cooper strip. What do you think?

Comment: The breaker doesn't have the lugs see https://imageshack.com/a/img923/5808/4iRTrJ.jpg    so if I buy the TCAL25, how can I put it? by just screwing it at bottom or do I have to open the breaker case?

Answer (score 1):

I contend that trying to repair that breaker is a very bad idea no matter small the repair.  They are not that expensive to buy new.  They are also available used. (This is only a slightly better solution.)

Comment: Why did you say repairing the breaker. It's just changing the cooper strip to screws. I guess the cooper strip is just put on top of the existing lugs, or does it an entirely different lugs for the cooper strip?

Answer (score 1):

### You can't lug-kit miniature breaker frames

Breakers of this general design type (double-size miniature breakers) are not equipped to accept what is called a *lug kit* that allows field conversion between connection types as a general rule, unlike their bigger brothers (known as *molded case* circuit breakers in the industry).

So, you'll need to get an entirely new breaker for this, one that has line and load lugs factory fitted.  The correct GE part number for the new breaker is a GE TQD22125WL -- you should be able to get this through an electrical supply house that carries GE's line of products.

Comment: But isnt the TQD22125 a molded case circuit breaker? You mean in the installed unit (pictured), there is no TCAL25 aluminum lugs beneath the cooper strip? Im imagining there is so i can just remove the cooper strip and insert wire to the lugs and put set screw.. and what is the difference between my tqd22125 and tqd22125wl? They are same size isnt it?

Comment: @Jtl -- they use the same frame, but there isn't a listed/labeled retrofit lug kit for that frame, best I can tell.

Comment: How was the cooper strip connected to it then? Not on top of existing lugs? Im assuming there is normal lugs beneath it so pls emphasize how the cooper strip is connected to the breaker. Thanks. This is pic of it all http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/803/OE1xyD.jpg

Comment: Here is the photo underneath it... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/923/4iRTrJ.jpg  You are right ThreePhaseEel, there is no existing lugs. I was thinking there was and the cooper was just screwed inside the lugs. So now I'll instead buy din rail 100A or 125A main breaker which are mostly used in new condominiums and houses in the country now. Thanks for making me realize it I nearly ordered the TCAL25. But just for knowledge. Do you know even the GE TQD22125 without the WL has lugs above and below it? So the difference with TQD22125 is it is removable? What does WL stand for?

Comment: @Jtl -- the TQD22125 without the WL is going to be set up probably for wires on one end and bolt-down on the other, as your breaker is.  The WL on the part number means it will have lugs on both ends.

Comment: But look at this https://imageshack.com/a/img923/5663/2HKWhz.jpg the model is TQD22150 as you can see in the breaker itself (zoom in) yet both ends are lugs where wires can be directly inserted.. therefore the WL doesn't mean lugs at both ends. what does WL mean then?

Comment: @Jtl -- the photo you just linked depicts the WL variant.

Comment: Where is the WL written? Its my stand alone disconnect before the main 125A panel.  There is another one just like in in the street see https://imageshack.com/a/img921/4540/yfIaRs.jpg how do the breakers without WL look like? how to distinguish them by the labels?

Comment: @Jtl -- it's not denoted in the part number on the label, apparently.  The ones that are WL seem to have a "TCAL25 CONNECTORS" marking on them somewhere that I don't see on your specimen, but I can't read the label in the photo in your OP.  If you could post a clear photo of that, that'd help...

Comment: this one is the disconnect inside https://imageshack.com/a/img921/1323/O2qjht.jpg here is the pic outside (click zoom) to see label clearly https://imageshack.com/a/img921/9100/9LKE6l.jpg

Comment: That is curious then....

Comment: in case the main breaker with cooper strip at load side is a WL in disguished. If I buy the TCAL25 lug kit, can I just screw it below or do I have to open the unit (meaning not field convertible)?

Comment: I finally removed the GE TQD breaker. Here is the front of it https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6088/qo91NO.jpg, maybe older version allowed the TCAL25 lug kit even without the WL in the model? Also looking at these lugs, they can surely fit. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/175/SqEwML.jpg  I can keep the breaker as backup to my other existing ones. Do you think I should sandpaper the terminal first? Shouldn't they look cooper?