# Connecting AWG 1 Wires

Tags: electrical-panel

What is the best way to connect two AWG 1 wire together especially when it is the main feeder before the main panel?

You can't just wire it manually or even use wire nuts.

Are there special lugs where you can wire them together with plastic housing (not the ground lugs where it is all exposed steel and so dangerous as it would be put in panel).

Something that is breaker like that pass through AWG 1 and has capacity of at least 125A?

Comment: Are you kidding hot wiring that size wiring is sketchy for pros with hot gloves and flash shields more info is needed , and probably not advisable for a non pro without a flash suit , hot gloves, and a full face shield.

Comment: No. wrong word. I mean just connecting it with all power source OFF. I'll edit it thanks..

Comment: Harper wrote me & used the word "hotwire" in the comment of the post https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156688/what-to-put-in-60a-gfci-breakers-in-subpanel/156689?noredirect=1#comment262372_156689 "You can unscrew the screws at the top of the busbars in that photo. Then it should be possible to fit lugs where the busbars were. Remember, all of this is downline of a 150A breaker which is outside. If your feeder wire is adequate to 150A, and as I revealed, 38mm2 wire is indeed adequate... then can hotwire straight to the Siemens panel's main. Then, from a 60A GFCI to the top of the GE main"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insulated lug connectors made by Polaris, Burndy, and others are what you're looking for:

[image: Insulated Lug Connector]

They are expensive but if you follow the directions to the letter they are not hard to use.

Comment: I do agree these are awesome. The cost ends up being about the same for me compared to split bolts and then cambric, linerless and super88 tapes on motors that get swapped out after the first swap they become cheaper and are much quicker.+

Answer (score 0):

Use a connection block rated for the current you plan to put though them.

[image]